# Phonegap build fails with cordova-facebook-plugin4 and minsdkversion=26

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap

Platform: Phonegap CLI 7.1.0 crosswalk 2.2.0
Until now I've been building with success using minsdkversion=15 in my config.xml file.

I tried to change minsdkversion from 15 to 26 in my config.xml (Google starting from august will require it) and I got this error:

uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:22.52.561.4] /build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.xwalk/xwalk_core_library/22.52.561.4/AndroidManifest.xml

so I tried to understand which plugin was in error and I found cordova-facebook-plugin4 (removing it the building succeeds)

So I wrote to author of the plugin who suggested to me to fork the project and to change minsdkversion in plugin.xml from 15 to 26. I did it and I changed my config.xml in order to use that git repo.

The build fails with this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

What it means? how to fix the problem?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this problem is that cordova will overwrite your `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file when you do a build.  Check if your minSdkVersion in the manifest keeps your change to 26 after you do a build.  If it doesn't, you'll want to add the following to the `build` command:

`-- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=26`

So for cordova it would be:

`cordova build android -- --gradleArg=-PcdvMinSdkVersion=26`

Undo your forking of the plugin, add the original one back in, and give that build command a shot.

Comment: Hello I use phonegap site to build, can I set that command even in this way? And again, without that plugin the build succeeds, so I think the problem is in the plugin, isn'it?

Comment: @AlessandroSbenaglia `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library` is telling you that the plugin is saying the min SDK targetted must be above 15 so it is complaining about a setting.

Comment: @AlessandroSbenaglia I never even knew the adobe cloud for phonegap existed until now.  I have no idea how to force gradle to use a certain setting, but if you can figure out how to force the minSdkVersion to 16+ that will fix your issue.